# I am working on web forms, created a page where I am using datepicker and a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on web forms, created a page where I am using datepicker and a textbox. I want to know how to get "From" date and "TO" date from the user and display all dates in that week in textboxes. So, I have 7 textboes to get displayed.

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace TimesheetApplication
{
    public partial class time : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<DateTime> datetime;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnDateSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dt1 = date1.ToString();
            string dt2 = date2.ToString();

            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse(dt1);
            DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(dt2);

            List<DateTime> dates = GetDatesBetween( d1.Date, d2.Date).ToList();

        //need to get the dates displayed

        }

        protected DateTime[] GetDatesBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();
            for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
                allDates.Add(date);
            return allDates.ToArray();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: could you show what you have tried?

Comment: If you are always going to have 7 days, why have them select a "TO" date? Just calculate it from the selected "FROM" date. If you let them select both, what happens if there are more than, or less than 7 days between the dates?

Comment: yeah, i will change as you said. but i am struggling to display all the dates into text boxes

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected DateTime[] GetDatesBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();
        for (int i=-(int)startDate.DayOfWeek, j=0;j<7;j++,i++)
            {
                allDates.Add(startDate.AddDays(i));
            }
        return allDates.ToArray();
    }
```

This starts the week on sunday. To start on a different day of the week, add an integer to i.

Comment: how to display all the dates into textboxes?

Comment: @srinathkumar `TextBox1.Text=datetime[0].ToShortDateString();`  `TextBox2.Text=datetime[1].ToShortDateString();`

Comment: @srinathkumar. Glad I could help :-). Accepting my answer will help other users see that this answer worked for you.